# How to know how many people have installed my android/iOS app via a facebook ad?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, ads, facebook-ads-api

I have an ad(android/iOS) campaign running on facebook. Currently on the app manager(ap dashboard) I'm getting the following information: Campaign reach, frequency, clicks etc but the 'mobile app installs' field is displaying 0 even after my friend installed it via the facebook ad. How to know how many people have installed my android/iOS app via a facebook ad?

Comment: Are you calling activateApp in your app?

Comment: No. What do I have to do for that to happen?

Comment: Did you specify the `mobile_app_install` tracking spec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you follow all the steps here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads

Especially the section "Add the Facebook SDK". In it, it tells you where to call either

```
[FBAppEvents activateApp]; // for iOS
```

or

```
AppEventsLogger.activateApp(...); // for Android
```

Which tells Facebook that the app was successfully installed. Otherwise, Facebook would not know that the app was installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get userid of user when he/she logs in into your application, and store this id to server. And thus come to know how many people have installed your application.

Comment: But this will give me the number of people who have clicked on the facebook ad right? How will we know if the user has gone ahead and installed it too?

Comment: can u explain me in detail...?

Comment: The facebook ads displayed just redirects the user to the android play store/iOS app store when he clicks on the ad and there the user can download the app. I just want to know how many have gone ahead after clicking the ad to download the app. Right now on the ad dashboard on my facebook profile the 'total app installs' field is 0 which shouldn't be the case since my friends have downloaded the app via the ad on facebook. Is there some setting on facebook that I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but couldn't figure it out. Even on my app  dashboard the 'mobile app installs' field is showing 0